# Clean install of OEM Windows7 from HDD to SSD

Tags: windows-7, installation, ssd

I have an Acer laptop and I want to install Win7 on my new SSD drive. What I'd like to do is to have a fresh install.

My HDD has two hidden partitions (PQSERVICE and unnamed) before C:.

I tried downloading a Win7 legit ISO from digitalriver but the product key on the back of my laptop won't work. BTW, the label is partially eroded, I don't know if the key I entered is 100% right. I've tried tools like Magical Jelly Bean but on my current Win7 installation but the product key they detect is totally different (I guess there's a license problem?)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it the same version (Pro, Ultimate...)

Comment: `Magical Jelly Bean` is a scam, don't bother with buying the full version, it still won't work. The only program that let me view the correct license key in a Windows installation is Belec advisor.  Since I too have experience the wrong license key being displayed AFTER I bought it, so save your money, and use a free product.

Comment: Try Produkey, I've always had success with that. No installation required.

Comment: @moses: I've tried but the license key is the same displayed by Magical Jelly Bean. I've head some pc come with two serials, one for recovery and one for fresh install

Comment: @cranio No, that is not accurate. There is one product key for one licensed copy of Windows.

Comment: @Moses: oh well, then I got it wrong, sorry and thanks for your help.